# Python is looking at characters instead of the full string/element in the array, for youtube-dl

Tags: python, arrays, youtube-dl

I'm trying to loop through an array of URLs and have youtube-dl download one URL per pass. Instead what's happening is it's trying to process each *character* one at a time. I'm pretty new to Python, thanks for any help/pointers you can give.

I think this is probably a pretty simple fix but I've been looking since yesterday and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried explicitly converting the array element to a string with str() but still had the same issue.

I also tried escaping the single quotes with r""" so that what's being passed to youtube-dl is actually single-quote wrapped in case that was the issue.

```
videos = [r"""'https://vimeo.com/231870662'""",
          r"""'https://vimeo.com/242969384'""",
          r"""'https://vimeo.com/251875303'""",
          r"""'https://vimeo.com/253315269'"""]

for vid in videos:
    ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors' : True}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(vid)
```

I was expecting it would just process the URLs one at a time. Instead it seems to be trying to process each character one at a time. Error message below.

```
ERROR: "'" is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  
youtube-dl "ytsearch:'" ) to search YouTube
ERROR: 'h' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  
youtube-dl "ytsearch:h" ) to search YouTube
ERROR: 't' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  
youtube-dl "ytsearch:t" ) to search YouTube
ERROR: 't' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  
youtube-dl "ytsearch:t" ) to search YouTube
ERROR: 'p' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  
youtube-dl "ytsearch:p" ) to search YouTube
ERROR: 's' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  
youtube-dl "ytsearch:s" ) to search YouTube
```

...and so on, for each character.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in `vid`. It seems you have single char instead of url.  Maybe you made `videos = videos[0]` and now `for` loop takes single chars from first url instead of getting urls from list. And you don't have to use `'` and `"""` at the same time - it will create invalid url with `' '` - use `[ 'https://vimeo.com/231870662', ...]`

Comment: Apparently the `.download()` function expects to receive a list of urls, not a single string url.  Try this instead: `ydl.download([vid])`  Or just `ydl.download(videos)`, assuming you strip out the extraneous quotes.

Comment: That solved it, thanks you so much! Apparently I just needed to wrap the vid in brackets, I didn't think those were necessary since I was passing it a variable instead of a list of values.

Comment: Working snippet in case it helps anyone in the future

            ydl.download([vid])